# Count specific value in database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Take a look of my query:

```
<?php
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
  $query = mysqli_query($db,"select count(categoryName) as total from categories");
  $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  echo $result['total'];
?>
```

This query is `count` how many `categoryName` in the `categories` table.
Say its return 3. and These 3 are Full Time, Part Time and Contractual.Now i want to count how many `Full Time` data in the `categories` table.Let me know if you need any further info of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding a `where` clause to your query. Here is an example:

```
mysqli_query($db,"select count(categoryName) as total from categories where categoryName = 'Full Time'");
```

In response to the OP's comment, you can get the count of rows that have the same value for the column `categoryName` using a query like this one:

```
SELECT categoryName AS name, count(*) AS total FROM categories GROUP BY categoryName;
```

Example:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT categoryName AS name, count(*) AS total FROM categories GROUP BY categoryName;");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $result['name'] . " " . $result['total'];
}
```

I haven't written PHP in a while, the example above may have some syntax errors.

Comment: Ok i understand.but if `cwhere ategoryName =" somethingelse"` i want make `categoryName = " dynamicValueHere"`.i Want exactly this things http://prntscr.com/cqetpt